# Returning Mono<Object> instead of Mono<Void>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am new to Spring WebFlux. I have a blocking code in my reactive application that I am in wrapping in an another thread as suggested in this [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking). The blocking code and the wrapping function doesn't have any return type. So I am using the following snippet of code.

```
    public Mono<Void> wrappingFunction(String param) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

            // do the blocking operation
            return null;

        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
```

The above code snippet gives the error that `Required type: Mono <Void>, Provided: Mono <Object>`. When I change void to a string it works as shown below but ideally it should be void as it is not returning anything. Could someone please tell how I can handle this correctly?

```
    public Mono<String> wrappingFunction(String param) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

            // do the blocking operation
            return param;

        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
```

Comment: Why `fromCallable` as that has a return type, why not just `Mono.just` or `Mono.fromRunnable`?